# Token error with MobileFirst on Android in Bluemix

Tags: android, node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-mobile-services

I'm trying [the Bluelist demo on Android](http://pt.slideshare.net/ibmdeveloperworks/blue-list-pushandroid) and I'm receiving the error below...

It looks like the mobile service is throwing a `401`.

```
11-03 19:42:52.469  31488-31527/com.ibm.bluelist E/com.ibm.mobile.services.core.http.IBMMutableHttpRequest﹕ Request to 'https://winmobile.mybluemix.net/data/helo' failed. IBMBLUEMIX-0300E: Request by com.ibm.mobile.services.data.IBMData was rejected by MAS.  Status=401, Response={"error":"You are not authorized.","status":"failure"}
    .
11-03 19:42:52.479  31488-31508/com.ibm.bluelist E/getToken(34252)﹕ Server rejected request for with status code 401
    com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.HttpFailure: Http Response Code: 401
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection.getToken(Connection.java:199)
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection.access$400(Connection.java:43)
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection$Receiver.run(Connection.java:412)
11-03 19:42:52.479  31488-31508/com.ibm.bluelist E/Connection:Receiver(34252)﹕ Http Response Code: 401
    com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.HttpFailure: Http Response Code: 401
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection.getToken(Connection.java:199)
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection.access$400(Connection.java:43)
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection$Receiver.run(Connection.java:412)
11-03 19:42:52.599  31488-31532/com.ibm.bluelist E/com.ibm.mobile.services.core.http.IBMMutableHttpRequest﹕ Request to 'https://winmobile.mybluemix.net/push/v1/apps/58cf6be4-9e6f-4f10-910c-178ebed2883a/settings/current' failed. IBMBLUEMIX-0300E: Request by com.ibm.mobile.services.push.IBMPush was rejected by MAS.  Status=401, Response=Error 401: {
    &quot;error&quot;: &quot;MASS016E: Invalid application secret is detected.&quot;
    }
    .
```

My logs full logs are below.

```
11-03 19:42:50.189  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist E/Zygote﹕ MountEmulatedStorage()
11-03 19:42:50.189  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist E/Zygote﹕ v2
11-03 19:42:50.189  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist I/libpersona﹕ KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10086
11-03 19:42:50.189  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist I/libpersona﹕ KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
11-03 19:42:50.209  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SM-G900M_5.0 ver=27
11-03 19:42:50.209  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [1] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-G900M_5.0_0027
11-03 19:42:50.209  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist E/SELinux﹕ [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
11-03 19:42:50.209  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-03 19:42:50.259  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist D/TimaKeyStoreProvider﹕ TimaSignature is unavailable
11-03 19:42:50.259  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist D/ActivityThread﹕ Added TimaKeyStore provider
11-03 19:42:50.379  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist D/ResourcesManager﹕ creating new AssetManager and set to /data/app/com.ibm.bluelist-2/base.apk
11-03 19:42:50.519  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist I/BlueListApplication﹕ Found configuration file: bluelist.properties
11-03 19:42:50.519  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist I/BlueListApplication﹕ Application ID is: 58cf6be4-9e6f-4f10-910c-178ebed2883a
11-03 19:42:50.889  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist I/com.ibm.mobile.services.core.IBMBluemix﹕ IBMBluemix SDK initialization successful.
    IBMBluemix SDK Version: 1.0.1.20150311-1224
    BlueMix Target: https://winmobile.mybluemix.net
    applicationId: 58cf6be4-9e6f-4f10-910c-178ebed2883a
11-03 19:42:51.319  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist I/com.ibm.mobile.services.data.IBMData﹕ IBMData SDK initialization successful.
    IBMData SDK Version: 1.0.0.20150311-1224
11-03 19:42:51.389  31488-31527/com.ibm.bluelist I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: SBServiceAPI: getService class android.os.ServiceManager
11-03 19:42:51.389  31488-31527/com.ibm.bluelist I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
11-03 19:42:51.389  31488-31527/com.ibm.bluelist I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Thread-34254-140709693: SmartBonding Enabling is true, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
11-03 19:42:51.499  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist I/com.ibm.mobile.services.push.IBMPush﹕ IBMPush SDK initialization successful.
    IBMPush SDK Version: 1.0.0.20150311-1224
11-03 19:42:51.589  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist I/com.ibm.mobile.services.push.IBMPush﹕ IBMPushInvoker : Sending request to the Push server. Method : GET Request URL : https://winmobile.mybluemix.net/push/v1/apps/58cf6be4-9e6f-4f10-910c-178ebed2883a/settings/current
11-03 19:42:51.649  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist D/BlueListApplication﹕ Activity created: MainActivity
11-03 19:42:51.679  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist V/BitmapFactory﹕ DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/ic_ab_back_holo_dark_am.png
11-03 19:42:51.739  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist V/BitmapFactory﹕ DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/sym_def_app_icon.png
11-03 19:42:51.749  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist V/BitmapFactory﹕ DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-mdpi-v4/plusbutton.png
11-03 19:42:51.769  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
11-03 19:42:51.779  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist V/BitmapFactory﹕ DecodeImagePath(decodeResourceStream3) : res/drawable-mdpi-v4/logo.png
11-03 19:42:51.789  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist D/Activity﹕ performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
11-03 19:42:51.789  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist D/Activity﹕ performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
11-03 19:42:51.789  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist D/BlueListApplication﹕ Activity started: MainActivity
11-03 19:42:51.789  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist D/BlueListApplication﹕ Activity resumed: MainActivity
11-03 19:42:51.869  31488-31535/com.ibm.bluelist D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
11-03 19:42:51.979  31488-31535/com.ibm.bluelist I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.01.03
    Build Date: 03/03/15 Tue
    Local Branch: LA.BF.1.1_RB1_20150108_025_1077123_1158499
    Remote Branch:
    Local Patches:
    Reconstruct Branch:
11-03 19:42:51.989  31488-31535/com.ibm.bluelist I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-03 19:42:52.009  31488-31535/com.ibm.bluelist I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ HWUI protection enabled for context ,  &this =0xafcfe718 ,&mEglDisplay = 1 , &mEglConfig = 8
11-03 19:42:52.009  31488-31535/com.ibm.bluelist D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
11-03 19:42:52.309  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@133d7119 time:123916211
11-03 19:42:52.469  31488-31527/com.ibm.bluelist E/com.ibm.mobile.services.core.http.IBMMutableHttpRequest﹕ Request to 'https://winmobile.mybluemix.net/data/helo' failed. IBMBLUEMIX-0300E: Request by com.ibm.mobile.services.data.IBMData was rejected by MAS.  Status=401, Response={"error":"You are not authorized.","status":"failure"}
    .
11-03 19:42:52.479  31488-31508/com.ibm.bluelist E/getToken(34252)﹕ Server rejected request for with status code 401
    com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.HttpFailure: Http Response Code: 401
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection.getToken(Connection.java:199)
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection.access$400(Connection.java:43)
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection$Receiver.run(Connection.java:412)
11-03 19:42:52.479  31488-31508/com.ibm.bluelist E/Connection:Receiver(34252)﹕ Http Response Code: 401
    com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.HttpFailure: Http Response Code: 401
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection.getToken(Connection.java:199)
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection.access$400(Connection.java:43)
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection$Receiver.run(Connection.java:412)
11-03 19:42:52.599  31488-31532/com.ibm.bluelist E/com.ibm.mobile.services.core.http.IBMMutableHttpRequest﹕ Request to 'https://winmobile.mybluemix.net/push/v1/apps/58cf6be4-9e6f-4f10-910c-178ebed2883a/settings/current' failed. IBMBLUEMIX-0300E: Request by com.ibm.mobile.services.push.IBMPush was rejected by MAS.  Status=401, Response=Error 401: {
    &quot;error&quot;: &quot;MASS016E: Invalid application secret is detected.&quot;
    }
    .
11-03 19:42:52.599  31488-31532/com.ibm.bluelist I/com.ibm.mobile.services.push.IBMPush﹕ IBMPushInvoker : Received response for GET https://winmobile.mybluemix.net/push/v1/apps/58cf6be4-9e6f-4f10-910c-178ebed2883a/settings/current : Response = 401 Unauthorized
11-03 19:42:52.649  31488-31532/com.ibm.bluelist E/com.ibm.mobile.services.push.IBMPush﹕ Error while retrieving GCM SenderId from server: Status Code : 401, Status Line : Unauthorized
11-03 19:42:52.659  31488-31581/com.ibm.bluelist E/com.ibm.mobile.services.push.IBMPush﹕ Registration failed Status Code : 401, Status Line : Unauthorized
11-03 19:42:52.669  31488-31581/com.ibm.bluelist E/BlueListApplication﹕ Exception : Status Code : 401, Status Line : Unauthorized
11-03 19:42:52.959  31488-31572/com.ibm.bluelist E/com.ibm.mobile.services.core.http.IBMMutableHttpRequest﹕ Request to 'https://winmobile.mybluemix.net/data/helo' failed. IBMBLUEMIX-0300E: Request by com.ibm.mobile.services.data.IBMData was rejected by MAS.  Status=401, Response={"error":"You are not authorized.","status":"failure"}
    .
11-03 19:42:52.969  31488-31509/com.ibm.bluelist E/getToken(34253)﹕ Server rejected request for with status code 401
    com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.HttpFailure: Http Response Code: 401
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection.getToken(Connection.java:199)
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection.access$400(Connection.java:43)
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection$Sender.run(Connection.java:516)
11-03 19:42:52.969  31488-31509/com.ibm.bluelist W/Connection:Sender(34253)﹕ com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.HttpFailure: Http Response Code: 401
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection.getToken(Connection.java:199)
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection.access$400(Connection.java:43)
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection$Sender.run(Connection.java:516)
11-03 19:42:52.969  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist E/MainActivity﹕ Exception : Http Response Code: 401
11-03 19:42:53.539  31488-31527/com.ibm.bluelist E/com.ibm.mobile.services.core.http.IBMMutableHttpRequest﹕ Request to 'https://winmobile.mybluemix.net/data/helo' failed. IBMBLUEMIX-0300E: Request by com.ibm.mobile.services.data.IBMData was rejected by MAS.  Status=401, Response={"error":"You are not authorized.","status":"failure"}
    .
11-03 19:42:53.539  31488-31508/com.ibm.bluelist E/getToken(34252)﹕ Server rejected request for with status code 401
    com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.HttpFailure: Http Response Code: 401
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection.getToken(Connection.java:199)
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection.access$400(Connection.java:43)
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection$Receiver.run(Connection.java:412)
11-03 19:42:53.539  31488-31508/com.ibm.bluelist E/Connection:Receiver(34252)﹕ Http Response Code: 401
    com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.HttpFailure: Http Response Code: 401
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection.getToken(Connection.java:199)
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection.access$400(Connection.java:43)
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection$Receiver.run(Connection.java:412)
11-03 19:43:06.789  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-03 19:43:12.339  31488-31488/com.ibm.bluelist D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-03 19:43:13.109  31488-32236/com.ibm.bluelist E/com.ibm.mobile.services.core.http.IBMMutableHttpRequest﹕ Request to 'https://winmobile.mybluemix.net/data/helo' failed. IBMBLUEMIX-0300E: Request by com.ibm.mobile.services.data.IBMData was rejected by MAS.  Status=401, Response={"error":"You are not authorized.","status":"failure"}
    .
11-03 19:43:13.109  31488-31509/com.ibm.bluelist E/getToken(34253)﹕ Server rejected request for with status code 401
    com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.HttpFailure: Http Response Code: 401
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection.getToken(Connection.java:199)
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection.access$400(Connection.java:43)
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection$Sender.run(Connection.java:516)
11-03 19:43:13.109  31488-31509/com.ibm.bluelist W/Connection:Sender(34253)﹕ com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.HttpFailure: Http Response Code: 401
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection.getToken(Connection.java:199)
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection.access$400(Connection.java:43)
            at com.ibm.mobile.services.data.internal.Connection$Sender.run(Connection.java:516)
11-03 19:43:13.109  31488-31509/com.ibm.bluelist E/MainActivity﹕ Exception : Http Response Code: 401
```

Can anyone help

Answer (score 1):

```
MASS016E: Invalid application secret is detected
```

Seems to be the root cause there. Please verify that you followed slide 14 from that slideshow and added your application secret (obtained from the Bluemix dashboard under the MAS service) to the bluelist.properties file.

If you are interested though I would actually recommend taking a look at the 2nd Generation Mobile Services Android Bluelist example as it uses more up-to-date SDKs and offers a better toolset for developers than the first generation services you would be using following the example you provided. You can find the github for that project [here](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-android-bluelist) and the corresponding documentation on Bluemix [here](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/mobilefirst/gettingstarted/bluelist_sample_android.html)

Comment: Jamea, I do this yesterday (put clod secret app). I thing thd problem  is  in Google developers Console Number

Comment: Neuber, looking at our server logs it is certainly an issue with the MAS authorization, it is not even sending a request to GCM at this point. Please verify that your application secret was copied correctly and does not have any leading or trailing whitespace. Additionally if it still does not work I would suggest using the MBaaS REST API tool for obtaining GCMCredentials https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/mbaas-api/#!/push/getGCMCredentials_get_4 and seeing if that gives us any more info to debug with. Regards.

Comment: added to this problem, lacked the "https://" before the applicationRoute. Solved Thank's